# How to create a model containing arrays

Tags: android, model

I'm making a model for daily Forecast but I'm having some trouble with creating this model.
It has regular information (date, description...) but I need it to have various Strings of information in it for every 3 hours...(temperatures, wind speed, wind direction etc)
And that's where I don't know how to do it..maybe with an Array of some sort but not sure.

So far, here is what I have:

```
public class DayForecast implements Serializable{

private String date;
private String description;


public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Thx!

Comment: You want to take the above information every 3 hours, right? Are you generating the information every 3 hours on the device and then storing it? Or you get the data just one time from a HTTP request?

Comment: can you post the data that you are converting into this class object so that we can give exact class you need.

Comment: Thx! I get the data from an online API, a JsonObject in fact. I get the data one time when the App starts but then there is a pull to refresh action possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like an array of Strings would do it, since you mentioned temperature, wind-speed, wind-direction etc. I would create another model for that and store instances of it within the current one.

e.g.

```
public class WeatherCondition {

    private double mTemperature;
    private double mWindSpeed;
    private String mDirection;

    public WeatherCondition(double temperature, double windSpeed, String direction) {
        mTemperature = temperature;
        mWindSpeed = windSpeed;
        mDirection = direction;
    }

    // ... setter and getter methods ...
}
```

and

```
public class DayForecast {

    private String mDate;
    private String mDescription;
    private SparseArray<WeatherCondition> mWeatherConditions = new SparseArray<WeatherCondition>();

    public WeatherCondition getWeatherCondition(int timeInHours) {
        // return null if no weather condition was set
        WeatherCondition weatherCondition = mWeatherConditions.get(timeInHours);
        // or you could add some other logic here, if you would want the next available weather condition,
        // but make sure to reflect that in the method name
        return weatherCondition;
    }

    public void setWeatherCondition(int timeInHours, WeatherCondition weatherCondition) {
        mWeatherConditions.append(timeInHours, weatherCondition);
    }

    // ... other setter and getter methods
}
```

Comment: Thx! The thing is that from the JsonObject, everything comes as a String (http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/marine.ashx?q=-36.8799074%2C174.7565664&key=2f8cfeef9f30819661c899a380bba&format=json&tide=yes)

Comment: @Makoto I see, the source JsonObject wraps everything in a String, but that doesn't mean you'll have to keep it that way when parsing the Json to your object. The jsonObject.getDouble("key") will return the proper double value, even if it is a String in the original json.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`. With this you can implement the same with less hassle and in organized manner.

Example usage:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
data.put("description", your_string_description);
data.put("date", your_string_date);
data.put("other", your_string_other_information);

list.add(data);
```

And to get your data:

```
list.get(0).get("description"); //will return the string description in position 0
list.get(0).get("date"); //will return the string description in position 0 you can convert it to date if needed
```

note that the get(0) is the position in your arraylist since with this you can add more items let's say description.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use a HashMap, as you would have to check for nulls all over the place. I also wouldn't recommend using an ArrayList, as looking up a value for a specific time would require looping through the list.

Comment: I doubt on that and moreover as he mentioned he's using a JSON response from the webservice so in my opinion this is the best implementation. You are not required to loop to check for a specific value as well since you can manually set the position.

Comment: If it is already a JSON and parsing to a POJO isn't required, then why not simply keep it as a JSONObject ? I see no benefit in converting a JSONObject to a HashMap (Personally i'd still convert it to a POJO). Setting the position in an ArrayList would require to "fill up" the ArrayList with null values beforehand (e.g. 24 null values, one for each hour), else the index position would be meaningless.

Comment: Well, in the end it will still depend on how you will implement it and what is needed. Everyone has a different ways and styles in coding. I just shared my answer and in case this is not acceptable for you then I respect your opinion and we should just let him decide.